# How would a Roman refer to a great-great-great- . . . -great-grandparent?

Tags: classical-latin, affixes, familia

Referring to progressively more distance ancestors, I would list my

- *Pater* (father)
- *Avus* (grandfather)

After this point, it gets a bit shaky. [This](https://books.google.com/books?id=vJfzPId7PnEC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=latin+great-grandfather+using+magnus&source=bl&ots=UAbDtGXhPP&sig=x93AG7SRVeJBrslznpdSGYmn1Ck&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjotI63xJjLAhUMdj4KHbcaCdAQ6AEIJTAC#v=onepage&q=latin%20great-grandfather%20using%20magnus&f=false), for example, gives past ancestors as

- *Proavus* (great-grandfather)
- *Abavus* (great-great-grandfather)
- *Atavus* (great-great-great-grandfather)
- *Tritavus* (great-great-great-great-grandfather)

<sup>See also [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=blhFAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=latin+great-grandfather&source=bl&ots=hE7ZQS81Fh&sig=hiGNx9TRiDAUQy2LMoBA-8SwK-0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi056DNw5jLAhXCbj4KHbxpCtc4FBDoAQghMAE#v=onepage&q=latin%20great-grandfather&f=false).</sup>

I don't know how far back this system went on — I have yet to find anything further — although it seems somewhat absurd that someone should need to refer to someone this distantly related.

If I were to literally translate "grand" in this usage, I would end up with some form of *magnus*, which could then be applied as successive prefixes. However, I doubt that this has actually been used; it seems like a misrepresentation. The book I cited also gave *pro-* as meaning

> 'add one generation away from *ego*.'

This might then mean that my *atavus* could also be called my *pro-pro-proavus*. However, *pro-* can also be used to indicate steps in future generations — and may in fact have been used more commonly in this way.

What system was most commonly used in Classical Latin — the specific naming system, applicable to at least six generations back in time, the *pro-* system, which could apparently be used for an arbitrary number of generations (which I'm slightly more interested in here), or something completely different?

Comment: Tangentially, I wonder whether Horatius in *Maecenas atavis edite regibus* means great-great-great-grandparents or ancestry in general. I'm not even sure how many Romans even knew the difference between *atavus* and *tritavus*.

Comment: It is not so absurd. William I of England was the tritavus of Edward I, who was the tritavus of Henry VI. David I of Scotland was the tritavus of Robert I, who was the tritavus of James III (https://www.britroyals.com/royaltree.asp).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An interesting question to which I don't actually know a definitive answer, but I'll try to shed what light I can.

I glanced at the source you link and couldn't find *tritavus*, but it seems an obvious possibility that the prefix "tri" could refer to the number 3, in which case one could imagine going back further with *quartavus, quintavus, septavus*, and so on. Since the Romans used *sescenta* in the way we use "thousand/thousands/umpteen" ("There were like a thousand people there" = *Sescenta aderant*), one could even imagine *sescentavus* as "umpteenth-great-grandfather," though of course that's not attested, as far as I know. (However, further investigation proves that the first vowel of *tritavus* is short, which could imply that my derivation from 3 is incorrect.)

With relatives closer than five generations away, though, Latin actually has a lot more words distinguishing blood relatives than most languages. Maternal blood uncle and aunt are *avunculus* and *mátertera*. Paternal blood uncle and aunt are *patruus* and *amita*. (There were no specific words relating to in-laws, so your maternal aunt by marriage was just *avunculí uxor*.)

When cousins come in it starts getting complicated. Your paternal uncle's child is your *fráter/soror patruélis*. Your paternal aunt's children AND your maternal uncle's children are your *frátres/sorórés amitíní/æ*. Your maternal aunt's child is your *fráter/soror cónsobrínus/a*. Your plain old brothers and sisters are *frátrés/sorórés germání/æ*.

Unfortunately I have these from lecture notes, so I can't source them, but even if I could, I get so exhausted keeping them straight that I might just give up anyway.

Comment: Regarding tritavus, it's with the others under the section of "Prenominal Pro-" with the others, on page 50. Interesting answer, though; I was aware of similar structures on other languages (Old English, too, I believe), but I didn't know if it was also the case with Latin.

Comment: Ah, okay—I was reading too quickly and missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Attention, all my sources are post-Classical. Thus they do not entirely fit the question but I think they are very useful for the concept itself.

This is what I attested so far skimming these books:

https://books.google.com.br/books?id=BtlDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA80 - I found here up to produovicatavus, but there could be more.

https://books.google.com.br/books?id=z4ETdGOufBUC&pg=PP8 - I found here up to prooctotricatavus, but again there could be more.

Here is a very long list of ancestors:
0. Ego
1. Pater
2. Avus
3. Proavus
4. Abavus
5. Atavus
6. Tritavus
7. Protritavus
8. Quadritavus
9. Proquadritavus
10. Quintitavus
11. Proquintitavus
12. Seditavus
13. Proseditavus
14. Septitavus
15. Proseptitavus
16. Octotavus
17. Prooctavus
18. Nonitavus
19. Prononitavus
20. Decatavus
21. Prodecatavus
22. Undecatavus
23. Proundecatavus
24. Duodecatavus
25. Produodecatavus
26. Tredecatavus
27. Protredecatavus
28. Quadridecatavus
29. Proquadridecatavus
30. Quindecatavus
31. Proquindecatavus
32. Sedecatavus
33. Prosedecatavus
34. Septendecatavus
35. Proseptendecatavus
36. Octodecatavus
37. Prooctodecatavus
38. Novendecatavus
39. Pronovendecatavus
40. Vicatavus
41. Provicatavus
42. Univicatavus
43. Prounivicatavus
44. Duovicatavus
45. Produovicatavus
...
76. Octotricatavus
77. Prooctotricatavus

From this book I saw that you can basically do the same thing with descendants: https://books.google.com.br/books?id=uEY5AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA334.

So you can go:

1. Ego
2. Filius
3. Nepos
4. Pronepos
5. Abnepos
6. Atnepos
7. Trinepos
8. Protrinepos
9. Quadrinepos
   etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you name the books and summarize what you found? Google Books links are not equally visible to everyone; what is freely visible to you might not be to me. It'd be nice to know whether they are extending the system by analogy or listing attestations. I expect the tail of the list to be later than classical.

Comment: Oh sorry, no problem. The first book's title is gargantuan: 
Trophaei Europaei, Sive Tokeologias Illustrium Universalis, Exhibentis, 62. Majores, utpote 31. Progenitores [et] 31. Progenitrices usq[ue] in quintam generationem, Omnium Imperatorum, Regum, Electorum ... Quotquot hodie in Orbe Christiano supersunt, vel paulò ante nostram aetatem vixerunt ... Centuria Athenaea.

The second book's title is: 
Austriotokeologia, Maximili-Rodolpho-Matthiana

The third book is called: The New England Historical and Genealogical Register, Volumes 1-2.

Comment: They are definitely not classical, but personally I don't mind as long as it's good Latin.

Comment: I don't mind later influences either. It's just that the question was explicitly about classical Latin, so it's better to mention when an answer is post-classical.

Comment: @Joonas you are right. I will update my comment.

Comment: Great find. I've found a book from 1671 by a Colerus with a long title starting "Trauer-Sermon, Als Der Durchleuchtigste Fürst und Herr, Herr Friderich ..." (http://books.google.nl/books?id=Dk5JAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA78), which has decitavus, octitavus and sextitavus instead of decatavus, octotavus and seditavus. Note also that the first page of your second source has novitavus, while your first source has nonitavus throughout (Colerus also has the latter).

Comment: @JasperMay I find these things interesting. It is probably because this is such a medieval need (Romans wouldn't have needed such precise genealogy) that it took forever to actually define things so far back and it wasn't ever standardized. The good thing though is that they are pretty much mutually intelligible variants. I love how one can go so far back with such small words in Latin lol