# Do vocative forms of participles exist?

Tags: participle, vocative

I wondered if the vocative forms of participles really exist.

E.g. the vocative of `vocatus` would be `vocate`, same with `vocaturus` and `vocature`.
Both forms can be found on pages like Wiktionary ([vocate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vocate#Latin), [vocature](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vocature)).

A quick [search on packhum](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=vocature) shows that `vocature` could not be found anywhere.
I cannot find anything anywhere else about vocatives of participles.

Are these only fictional automatically generated forms or do they really exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Martial 8,75 it says

> Hic mihi de multis unus, Lucane, videtur,
> Cui merito dici 'mortue Galle' potest.

“Mortue Galle” was (or so commentators claim) a term from gladiatorial fights; the [Murmillo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murmillo) in Gallic armour was customarily greeted so.

I also found several examples for *moriture* on the Packhum website.

Comment: Thanks. The search @ALE posted let me found some other examples too.

Answer (score 5):

Sure! Try to do this kind of search: https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=iture

Answer (score 4):

The very opening line of Horace's Odes goes:

> *Maecenas atavis **edite** regibus…*
> You Maecenas, who descend from ancestors that were kings…

The vocative of the participle *editus* plays a prominent role.
There is [a question on who these *atavi* were](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/420/79) if you want to dig deeper.